# How to send mail from custom module?

Tags: module, magento-1, email

Data.php

```
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE = 'order_attachments_receive_email_notification';

    public function getEmailAddress() {
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('orderattachments/order_attachments_general/send_email_notification_to')
    }

    static public function sendMail($orderId) {  
    $order = Mage::getModel('orderattachments/orderattachments')->load($orderId);
    $attachmentId = $order->getOrderAttachmentsId();
    $orderId = $order->getOrderId();
    $comment = $order->getComment();
    $attachment = basename($order->getFile());
    try {
        $postObject = new Varien_Object();
        $post['order_id'] = $orderId;
        $post['comment'] = $comment;
        $post['file'] = $attachment;
        $postObject->setData($post);
        $customerEmail = Mage::helper('orderattachments')->getEmailAddress();

        $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

        $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
            ->setReplyTo($customerEmail)
            ->sendTransactional( 
                Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE),
                array('email'=>$customerEmail),
                $customerEmail,
                       null,
                       array('data' => $postObject)
        );
        if(!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
            throw new Exception('Not Sent');
        }           
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_R($e);
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
        return $errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
     Mage::helper('orderattachments')->sendMail($orderAttachmentModel->getOrderAttachmentsId());
```

config.xml

```
    <template>
        <email>
            <order_attachments_receive_email_notification translate="label" module="orderattachments">
                <label>Order Attachments Notification</label>
                <file>orderattachments/attachment_notification.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </order_attachments_receive_email_notification>
        </email>
    </template>
```

system.xml

```
    <send_email_notification_to translate="label">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>70</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>            
    </send_email_notification_to>
```

is this correct or not if not correct then tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: Please review the answer submitted and accept if it solved your problem. Alternately provide further feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the following mail function from anywhere within your code pool:

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$emailTemplate->setFromName('Your Store Name');
$emailTemplate->setBody($body);
$emailTemplate->setSubject($subject);
$emailTemplate->setType('html');
$emailTemplate->setToEmail('test@example.com');
$emailTemplate->send();
```

Which will use your store's configured emailer to send the email.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer shows how to send a simple HTML email. But the code you provided looks like you are trying to use transactional email templates (like the sales module does).

#### This works as follows

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

$emailTemplate->setDesignConfig([
    'area' => 'frontend',
    'store' => $storeId
]);

$emailTemplate->sendTransactional(
    $template,
    $sender,
    $recipientEmail,
    $recipientName,
    $variables,             // optional
    $storeId                // optional
);
```

#### Parameters

- `$storeId` is only necessary if you send the email from backend but need to use skin assets or translation from a specific store. If that's not the case, you can also remove the call to `setDesignConfig()`
- `$template` is an email template that you have to define in your modules `config.xml`:

  ```
  <global>
      <template>
          <email>
              <your_custom_email_id translate="label" module="your_module">
                  <label>Your custom eamail</label>
                  <file>your_custom_email.html</file>
                  <type>html</type>
              </your_custom_email_id>
          </email>
      </template>
  </global>
  ```

  In this example, `$template` would be `your_custom_email_id` and the email template should be located in `app/locale/en_US/template/email/your_custom_email.html`.

  To make it editable in "Transactional Emails", create a configuration field in `system.xml` like this:

  ```
  <label>Your custom email template</label>
  <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
  <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
  ```

  And assign `$template` to this configuration value. You should specify the default value in `config.xml` to be `your_custom_email_id`
- `$sender` can be one of the default store email addresses: "general", "sales" or "support" or as custom sender in the form `['name' => 'John Doe', 'email' => 'jd@example.com']`
- `$recipientEmail` is a single email address or an array of email addresses
- `$recipientName` is the recipient name or an array of names (same number of elements as `$recipientEmail`). You can use `null` to not add a name.
- `$variables` is an associative array of variables that can be used in the email template with directives like `{{var}}` and `{{if}}`